# UMD pattern for angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive, umd

I'm looking to open source an angular directive on npm and I'm trying to come up with the most universal pattern for doing so. How's this? I have 3 questions:

```
!function(name, make) {
  make = make()

  // 1. Is this line needed?
  var angular = require('angular')

  // 2. Is this line needed?
  angular.module(name, []).directive(name, make)

  if (typeof module != 'undefined') module.exports = make
  else this[name] = make

  // 3. Is this line needed?
  if (typeof define == 'function') define(function() { return make })
}('exampleDirective', function() {
  return function() {
    return {
      link: function (scope, label, atts) {}
    }
  }
});
```

1. Is `require('angular')` needed or is it safe to assume the angular variable exists?
2. Is it necessary to call `angular.module` and `angular.directive` in my definition or should only the consuming app(s) do this?
3. Do AMD environments need this or does the `module.exports` or global suffice?

Answer (score 1):

**1**

```
  // 1. Is this line needed?
  var angular = require('angular')
```

No. Applications that use your library must always import their own version of AngularJS.

**2**

```
  // 2. Is this line needed?
  angular.module(name, []).directive(name, make)
```

Yes. Applications will need to list your module `name` in their list of dependencies like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[name]);
```

**3**

```
  // 3. Is this line needed?
  if (typeof define == 'function') define(function() { return make })
}('exampleDirective', function() {
  return function() {
    return {
      link: function (scope, label, atts) {}
    }
  }
});
```

No. You can just put the directive on the module and other developers will be able to use it.